# WinRT No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

Tags: file-io, windows-8, windows-runtime, datareader

I am trying to read a file in my Windows 8 Store App. Here is a fragment of code I use to achieve this:

```
        if(file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var size = stream.Size;
            using(var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
            {
                DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream);
                uint numbytes = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
                string text = dataReader.ReadString(numbytes);
            }
        }
```

However, an exeption is thrown at line:

```
string text = dataReader.ReadString(numbytes);
```

Exeption message:

```
No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
```

How do I get by this?

Comment: Unusual, I didn't think WinRT still handles multi-byte encoding.  It does however point to a text file that isn't properly encoded.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to read file correctly using similar approach to suggested by duDE:

```
        if(file != null)
        {
            IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
            DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
            reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
        }
```

Can somebody please elaborate, why my initial approach didn't work?

Comment: It read the Notepad save encoding ASCII as "?" when char is Chinese.And I try `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`.Can help?

Comment: @lindexi ASCII encoding doesn't support Chinese characters. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead of `string text = dataReader.ReadString(numbytes)`:

```
dataReader.ReadBytes(stream);
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, this was the top result when search for the same error regarding UWP, see the below:

The code I had which was throwing the error (*no mapping for the unicode character exists..*):

```
  var storageFile = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(fileToken);
        using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
            {
                await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                var json = dataReader.ReadString((uint)stream.Size);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            }
        }
```

What I changed it to so that it works correctly

```
     var storageFile = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(fileToken);
        using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            T data = default(T);
            using (StreamReader astream = new StreamReader(stream.AsStreamForRead()))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(astream))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                data = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));
            }
            return data;
        }
```