# System.Text.Encoding in WinJS

Tags: windows-8, winjs

Is there an equivalent of

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent)
```

in WinJS (Windows 8 Store App written in javascript/HTML)?

EDIT. fileContent is a byte array.

Comment: What is fileContent, stream? array? what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: fileContent is a byte array. I am trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: I am trying to read file as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206590/winrt-no-mapping-for-the-unicode-character-exists-in-the-target-multi-byte-code but in WinJS

Comment: See my answer below, hope it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no strict equivalent of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString` in `WinJS`, but you can try implement file reading to string as follows:

```js
file.openReadAsync().done(function (stream) {
   var blob = MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream(file.contentType, stream);
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function(event) {
      var fileAsText = event.target.result;
   };

   reader.readAsText(blob, 'UTF-8');
});
```

In most cases (file upload via XHR, displaying file) you don't need to have file contents as text, so just use `Blob` then.

Comment: Ok works great, but you have one small error in your code: you forgot to add parenthesis after openReadAsync (it should be file.openReadAsync().done(...))

Comment: One more question - do you happen to know how to handle unicode symbols (file I am trying to read contains polish letters)

Comment: thanks, that was the only way i could read a text file from Excel with dutch characters (saved as encoding LATIN1)

Answer (score 0):

[CryptographicBuffer.convertBinaryToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.convertbinarytostring.aspx) can be used for this.

```
var crypt = Windows.Security.Cryptography;
var bytes; // = new Uint8Array(100);
// TODO - set bytes variable with uint8array
var buffer = crypt.CryptographicBuffer.createFromByteArray(bytes);
var text = crypt.CryptographicBuffer.convertBinaryToString(
    crypt.BinaryStringEncoding.utf8, buffer);
```

Comment: Using your approach I get runtime exception: "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page."